# GL_LIGHT only creating one light source

Tags: c++, opengl

Currently I am trying to illuminate an object with a light source and change the color of the object based on GL_COLOR_MATERIAL. For some reason, I am only able to see ONE light source being projected on to the model. I've tried various different positions and combination of light sources and I have noticed only GL_LIGHT0 functions.

I've also tried different combination of ambient/diffuse/materials with no success.

```
static const GLfloat ambient[4] = {0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1.0f};
static const GLfloat diffuse[4] = {0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f};
static const GLfloat position0[4] = {0.0f, 0.0f, 20.0f, 0.0f};
static const GLfloat position1[4] = {0.0f, 0.0f, -20.0f, 0.0f};
static const GLfloat front_mat_shininess[1] = {60.0f};
static const GLfloat front_mat_specular[4] = {0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f};
static const GLfloat front_mat_diffuse[4] = {0.5f, 0.28f, 0.38f, 1.0f};

static const GLfloat lmodel_ambient[4] = {1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f};
static const GLfloat lmodel_twoside[1] = {GL_FALSE};

glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
glDisable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);

///Enable lighting if item is a solid model
if(wireFlag == 1)
{
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, ambient);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, diffuse);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, position0);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);

    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_AMBIENT, ambient);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_DIFFUSE, diffuse);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_POSITION, position1);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT1);

    glLightModelfv(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_AMBIENT, lmodel_ambient);
    glLightModelfv(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_TWO_SIDE, lmodel_twoside);


    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SHININESS, front_mat_shininess);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SPECULAR, front_mat_specular);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_DIFFUSE, front_mat_diffuse);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This looks like it should work, but try to replace `GL_LIGHT0` with `GL_LIGHT1` and vice-versa and see if it still works.  If the lighting looks the same, your problem doesn't lie with GL_LIGHT1 but likely your scene / state.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several parameters (eg `GL_DIFFUSE`) which default to `0,0,0,0` for `GL_LIGHT1` .. `GL_LIGHT7` but something else (eg `1,1,1,1`) for `GL_LIGHT0`.  I don't know which one you've missed, but I bet you're relying on a default for both lights and it's "off" for `GL_LIGHT1`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was not aware of this with GL_LIGHT1 - 7. That solved my problem